# Rename all Materials in a scene with Python

Tags: python

Only just started playing with Python and have managed to work out how to change all objects names after a ton of google searches.

**for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
o.name = o.name.replace("grau", "Grey")**

Seems to do what I want, but I can't find a way to rename materials for all objects in the same fashion.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    mat.name = mat.name.replace("grau", "Grey")
```

- this will change all materials in the Blendfile, not just the ones occuring in the current scene.

Comment: Thank you Frederik, better than Google ! Regards.

Comment: np, could you upvote and accept the answer, so others won't have to check whether it's already solved?

Comment: Done. thank you again.